# Validating OR condition in PHP defined function

Tags: php, conditional-operator

The following code doesn't work, can someone suggest an alternative,

```
if ((!defined('admin')) || !defined('moderator')) {
die('Access Denied !');
}
```

Comment: remove () of the first defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!defined('admin') && !defined('moderator')) {
    die('Access Denied !');
}
```

1. You added too many ()
2. It should probably be an AND operator since you want to test whether the user is neither an admin and nor a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!defined('admin')) && !defined('moderator') {
  die('Access Denied !');
}
```